# How do I make the falloff rounded?

Tags: modeling

I'm brand new to Blender and am watching a tutorial on YouTube, but I'm having a problem at a certain part. When I drag the icing like around [33:25 in the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5Gb1VK98Wc&t=2005s) it just goes into a point instead of a rounded edge and it does the same thing no matter which falloff type I choose (sharp, smooth, sphere, etc.), and a bigger or smaller circle for the proportional falloff doesn't help either. It just changes the angle of the slope leading to the point.

[image: Screenshot of my Blender Window]

Comment: you've turned off the Subsurf modifier viewport visibility, maybe turn it on

Comment: Press G and scroll your mouse wheel while moving, to increase or decrease the range of action.

Comment: @moonboots Thank you it worked! I thought I had done that but I was toggling the solidify one instead.